# G Suite - get my own group memberships via API call?

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-people-api

My normal, non-admin G Suite users need to work out (programatically) whether they are in a specific G Suite group or not.

### Plan A - G Suite Admin SDK

It would appear that one can do that with this call:

```
https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/developers@example.com/hasMember/max@example.com
```

This does not work. If I authenticate as an admin, it works. But if I authenticate as max@example.com (note: I added all relevant scopes to token request), I get a 403 "Not Authorized to access this resource/api".

Is it intended that a user cannot query his own group membership via the G Suite Admin SDK?

### Plan B - Google People API

I tried this API:

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=memberships
```

This returns a successful 200 response, but the group membership is not in there. The response is something like this, which is basically the standard empty response for that API:

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/107804923746527240895",
  "etag": "%EgMBNy4aBEAABQc="
}
```

Which API call can I make to find out whether I'm in a group or not?

Answer (score 0):

### Is it intended that a user cannot query his own group membership via the G Suite Admin SDK?

As the name says - it is an **Admin** Software development Kit - designed for admins. So unfortunately not accessible by non-admin users.

### group membership is not in there

Unfortunately the People API only returns you

```
"domainMembership": {
        "inViewerDomain": true
      }
```

if you are an admin - so again not useful for you.

### Conclusion - it is currently not possible for a user to see his group memberships

However, [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=assignee:ziganotschka1@egs-sbt015.eu%20status:open) allows you to file [feature requests](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui). This would allow you to let Google know that an important feature is missing and users request for it to be implemented.